# docker-compose problems mounting the teamspeak data directory as a volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, teamspeak

I'm trying to start a teamspeak container and mount the sqlite files to the host. I use a fresh installed docker engine and docker-compose. I haven't done the post installation setup to run docker as non-root user ([docs](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user)). That's why I think I have problems when I mount the TS data folder `/opt/ts3server/sql/` ([docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/teamspeak)) to my host system. The `./teamspeak/` folder owns root but I gave it also r-w-x for everyone.

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  teamspeak:
    user: root
    image: teamspeak
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 9987:9987/udp
      - 10011:10011
      - 30033:30033
    volumes:
      - ./teamspeak/:/opt/ts3server/sql/
    environment:
      TS3SERVER_LICENSE: accept
```

error logs from teamspeak:

> teamspeak_1  | 2019-10-25 20:18:33.827157|INFO    |ServerLibPriv |   |TeamSpeak 3 Server 3.9.1 (2019-07-02 13:17:23)
>
> teamspeak_1  | 2019-10-25 20:18:33.827272|INFO    |ServerLibPriv |   |SystemInformation: Linux 4.19.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.67-2+deb10u1 (2019-09-20) x86_64 Binary: 64bit
>
> teamspeak_1  | 2019-10-25 20:18:33.827300|INFO    |ServerLibPriv |   |Using hardware aes
>
> teamspeak_1  | 2019-10-25 20:18:33.827484|INFO    |DatabaseQuery |   |dbPlugin name:    SQLite3 plugin, Version 3, (c)TeamSpeak Systems GmbH
>
> teamspeak_1  | 2019-10-25 20:18:33.827513|INFO    |DatabaseQuery |   |dbPlugin version: 3.11.1
>
> teamspeak_1  | 2019-10-25 20:18:33.827614|INFO    |DatabaseQuery |   |checking database integrity (may take a while)
>
> teamspeak_1  | 2019-10-25 20:18:33.844497|CRITICAL|DatabaseQuery |   |setSQLfromFile( file:properties_list_by_string_id.sql) failed

When I set anything else than `/opt/ts3server/sql/` the teamspeak server starts.
How can I make the mounted volume read and writable for teamspeak?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @rok Updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to mount the data directory of the TS3 server. The volume you mounted (`/opt/ts3server/sql/`) is used to store the sql scripts to create the database.

> This variable controls where the TeamSpeak server looks for sql files. Defaults to /opt/ts3server/sql/.
>   - [teamspeak docker docu](https://hub.docker.com/_/teamspeak)

you instead want to mount the data directory (`/var/ts3server/`) to the host sytsem:

```
version: '3'
services:
  teamspeak:
    user: root
    image: teamspeak
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 9987:9987/udp
      - 10011:10011
      - 30033:30033
    volumes:
      - ./teamspeak/:/var/ts3server/
    environment:
      TS3SERVER_LICENSE: accept
```